# Rewrite/Redirect directory structure to a query with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

This is an example format of the url structure:
`http://sitename.com/em/state-898899888/new.gif`  (new.gif is a directory)

I need some help/direction to dynamically redirect the previous url to `http://sitename.com/new.gif?item_name=state-898899888`

'em' & 'state-89889988' are not actual directories.

I just added em to the directory structure to give the rewrite/redirect rule something to filter on.  So, basically, any request for 'http://sitename.com/em' should get the next directory '/state-898899888' and append that as the value of item_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule should work (does the job for me):

```
RewriteRule ^em/([^/]+)/new\.gif$ /new.gif?item_name=$1 [L]
```

1. It supposed to be placed in .htaccess in website root folder. If placed elsewhere it may need to be adjusted a bit.
2. I assume that `new.gif` is constant/hardcoded. If it's dynamic (name can be changed from product to product), then rule needs to be modified (I cannot create a rule for all situations while having single URL example).